# Show hyperlink in createhtml

Tags: html, google-apps-script

In this example I try to show a simple grid with two createhtml's. The simple one (italic text) shows, but the hyperlink doesn't. How can I make the hyperlink visible?

```
function test() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test html')
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(4,1);
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Label'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createHTML('<a href="http://www.google.com">Try Google</a>').setId('dir'));
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, app.createHTML('<em>This is italic text</em>'));
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(app);
}
```

Thnx for great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createAnchor("try", "http://www.google.com"));
```

It will show the link. If you wish to have an Id for that element, try to wrap it inside a span or a div.

Answer (score 0):

createHTML in UiApp has a limited number of authorized HTML tags :

The supported tags are listed here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2012#march_2012

> Added the ability to include a limited set of HTML tags when working with UiApp widgets, in response to this issue. Here is the list of HTML tags that are permitted: B, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, CENTER, CAPTION, CITE, CODE, DIV, EM, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HR, I, LABEL, LEGEND, LI, OL, P, SPAN, STRONG, SUB, SUP, TABLE, TBODY, TD, THEAD, TITLE, TR, TT, UL

Use createAnchor('string text','string url') instead, [see doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor)